# Finding the Row number of a value in an array

Tags: excel, vba

**Update**

so i have added a count in, so if theres a match, add 1 to n. If not, n =0. If n = 1 then row = the number found. But why do i need to use a count why cant i use my original code.

```
lastrow = (subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row) + 1
lastcol = subtaskws.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
lastcollet = lastcol
lastcollet = Split(Cells(1, lastcol).Address, "$")(1)
lastrowST = subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
activitynum = AddTask.TextBoxid.Value + 1


Dim Ctrl, ArrayID, userformorder As Variant, j As Long, range1 As Range, os As Integer, col, listitems As String, templatesubtaskrow As Range, tmeplatemilestonerow As Range, newrowadded As Range
userformorder = Array("SubTaskID", "TextBoxsubtask", "ComboBoxDeliverableFormat", "TextBoxcheckedcomplete", "TextBoxformat", "TextBoxacceptancecriteria", "BudgetWorkloadTextBox", "ComboBoxOwner", "TextBoxTDSNumber", "TextBoxMilestone", "TextBoxTargetDeliveryDate", "ComboBoxW", "ComboBoxI", "ComboBoxe", "TextBoxP", "TextBoxLevel", "TextBoxInputQuality", "TextBoxNewInput", "TextBoxDelay", "TextBoxInternalVV", "TextBoxReviewer", "TextBoxDelivered", "ComboBoxNumIterations", "ComboBoxAcceptance", "ComboBoxProgress", "ComboBoxStatus", "ComboBoxFlowChart", "TextBoxActivitySheet", "TextBoxEvidenceofDelivery", "TextBoxComments") 'etc

Set range1 = subtaskws.Range("A3:A" & lastrowST)
Set templatesubtaskrow = subtaskws.Range("A4:" & lastcollet & "4")
ArrayID = range1.Value

With subtaskws
n = 0
For j = LBound(ArrayID) To UBound(ArrayID)
    If ArrayID(j, 1) = activitynum Then
    n = n + 1
    Else
    n = n
    End If
Next j

If n = 1 Then
newrow = j
Else
newrow = lastrow
End If



    Set newrowadded = subtaskws.Range(IDCol & newrow)
```

**Original Question**

I have a userform that fills in a sheet labelled subtasks. However, sometimes the info being inserted may be in the middle of the sheet eg. row 64 out of 140.

I want to search the array for a set value (activtiynum) and when found, equal newrow to this newly found row number. If the activtiynum isnt found, then newrow should equal the lastrow + 1.

However, the code below wont work and displays the correct row number in the msgbox but then always adds a new row at the end

```
'find lastrows, columns and cells
lastrow = (subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row) + 1
lastcol = subtaskws.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
lastcollet = lastcol
lastcollet = Split(Cells(1, lastcol).Address, "$")(1)
lastrowST = subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
activitynum = AddTask.TextBoxid.Value + 1


Dim Ctrl, ArrayID, userformorder As Variant, j As Long, range1 As Range, os As Integer, col, listitems As String, templatesubtaskrow As Range, tmeplatemilestonerow As Range, newrowadded As Range
userformorder = Array("SubTaskID", "TextBoxsubtask", "ComboBoxDeliverableFormat", "TextBoxcheckedcomplete", "TextBoxformat", "TextBoxacceptancecriteria", "BudgetWorkloadTextBox", "ComboBoxOwner", "TextBoxTDSNumber", "TextBoxMilestone", "TextBoxTargetDeliveryDate", "ComboBoxW", "ComboBoxI", "ComboBoxe", "TextBoxP", "TextBoxLevel", "TextBoxInputQuality", "TextBoxNewInput", "TextBoxDelay", "TextBoxInternalVV", "TextBoxReviewer", "TextBoxDelivered", "ComboBoxNumIterations", "ComboBoxAcceptance", "ComboBoxProgress", "ComboBoxStatus", "ComboBoxFlowChart", "TextBoxActivitySheet", "TextBoxEvidenceofDelivery", "TextBoxComments") 'etc

Set range1 = subtaskws.Range("A3:A" & lastrowST)
Set templatesubtaskrow = subtaskws.Range("A4:" & lastcollet & "4")
ArrayID = range1.Value

With subtaskws

For j = LBound(ArrayID) To UBound(ArrayID)
    If ArrayID(j, 1) = activitynum Then
        MsgBox range1(j).row
        newrow = range1(j).row
    Else
        newrow = lastrow
    End If
Next j


   .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.Insert


    Set newrowadded = subtaskws.Range(IDCol & newrow)

    templatesubtaskrow.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=newrowadded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your original code, you need something to tell it to exit the FOR LOOP. Otherwise, the next iteration after finding the match, it will potentially NOT find a match in the next cell.  This causes the code to hit your `ELSE` code thereby changing `newrow` to `lastrow`.  In addition the reason you say it "finds" it correctly is because you display the messagebox when it finds it. If that was moved outside of the FOR statement using 'newrow' it would not display the correct value.

Simplest solution, lets not do anything in the `for loop` that we don't need to and `exit for` when we match. We can set a variable indicating success or we can use your newrow variable (not yet intialized/dimmed) to determin success.

Note-This only works because you haven't initialized newrow as a variable.  You might need to check it for NULL/EMPTY/0 if you dim it to begin with.

Also, added END WITH. Remove it if you have it later. Should be more consistent with the functionality.

`Set newrowadded = subtaskws.Range(IDCol & newrow)` appears to be IN the with statement but references the WITH object directly instead of `.Range`

See updated code below.

```
'find lastrows, columns and cells
lastrow = (subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row) + 1
lastcol = subtaskws.Cells(2, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
lastcollet = lastcol
lastcollet = Split(Cells(1, lastcol).Address, "$")(1)
lastrowST = subtaskws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
activitynum = AddTask.TextBoxid.Value + 1


Dim Ctrl, ArrayID, userformorder As Variant, j As Long, range1 As Range, os As Integer, col, listitems As String, templatesubtaskrow As Range, tmeplatemilestonerow As Range, newrowadded As Range
userformorder = Array("SubTaskID", "TextBoxsubtask", "ComboBoxDeliverableFormat", "TextBoxcheckedcomplete", "TextBoxformat", "TextBoxacceptancecriteria", "BudgetWorkloadTextBox", "ComboBoxOwner", "TextBoxTDSNumber", "TextBoxMilestone", "TextBoxTargetDeliveryDate", "ComboBoxW", "ComboBoxI", "ComboBoxe", "TextBoxP", "TextBoxLevel", "TextBoxInputQuality", "TextBoxNewInput", "TextBoxDelay", "TextBoxInternalVV", "TextBoxReviewer", "TextBoxDelivered", "ComboBoxNumIterations", "ComboBoxAcceptance", "ComboBoxProgress", "ComboBoxStatus", "ComboBoxFlowChart", "TextBoxActivitySheet", "TextBoxEvidenceofDelivery", "TextBoxComments") 'etc

Set range1 = subtaskws.Range("A3:A" & lastrowST)
Set templatesubtaskrow = subtaskws.Range("A4:" & lastcollet & "4")
ArrayID = range1.Value

With subtaskws

For j = LBound(ArrayID) To UBound(ArrayID)
    If ArrayID(j, 1) = activitynum Then 'If we match, set newrow to the matched row and then exit the loop
        MsgBox range1(j).row
        newrow = range1(j).row
        Exit For
    End If
Next j

'If newrow is empty it means we didn't match. Add newrow as last row.
If IsEmpty(newrow) Then
    newrow = lastrow
    .Range("A" & newrow).EntireRow.Insert
End If


End With 'Added END WITH as you go back to referencing subtasksws directly not using with syntax

 Set newrowadded = subtaskws.Range(IDCol & newrow)

 templatesubtaskrow.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=newrowadded
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and code! Just for performance, what’s the best way of finding the value row? Would it be range.find, a loop, match, searching an array? Speed would be ideal as the column may have 500-1000 entries

Comment: I have just implemented the code, but i dont think the if isempty(newrow) is correct, as it produces an error when it cant find a match.

Comment: Try `dim newrow as Range` along with your other vars and change the If to `If newrow Is Nothing`

Comment: Also regarding your speed question - stick with the array approach you have.  Arrays generally beat everything else for searching, but when in doubt - time it.